# How can i read data with column names which exported from hbase to hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hbase, rdd

I use hbase export tool to put hbase data to hdfs :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export \
   <tablename> <outputdir>
```

And i see data on my **hdfs**

when i want to read that data from hdfs , i convert data to readable csv with spark;

```
hadoop_conf = {"io.serializations": "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ResultSerialization"}

    sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    <input_path>,
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat',
     keyClass='org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable',
     valueClass='org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result',
     keyConverter='org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter',
     valueConverter='org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter',
     conf=hadoop_conf)
```

And when i take **10** record from **RDD** i see just key,value pairs.

I want to see also column names. Because i have different column names for by row.

So how can i convert my exported file to data that shows column names for each row.